# PHPdoc field inheritance : Field 'xxx' not found in 'xxx'

Tags: php, inheritance, phpdoc

I am trying to document my code and to remove my IDE warnings on my code. I'm working with IntelliJ IDEA.

I have two classes, the first is an abstract `Controller` like this :

```
abstract class Controller {
   /** @var Service $service */
   public static $service;
   ...
}
```

The second one is a `UserController`, which extends the first :

```
/** @property UserService $service */
abstract class UserController extends Controller {
   public static function testService() {
      static::$service->testMethod();
   }
   ...
}
```

My issues :

- If I declare a new function on the `UserService` without the `@property` tag, my IDE is telling me that `Method 'testMethod' not found in Service`
- If I use the `@property`, the IDE is telling me that `Field '$service' not found in UserController`

How can I fix this ?

Comment: The `@var` in the parent class should be enough by itself... the `@property` on the child should not be used, much less required.

I think you're seeing a limitation of your IDE, because the `@var` alone with the class inheritance should be enough... it certainly will be in Eclipse and PhpStorm.

Comment: The `$service` is well detected as a `Service` (the superclass) in both components, but I want to be a `UserService` which extends `Service`un my `ServiceController`. So the @var did something, but not what I want

Comment: Ah, missed that as being the intention.  In that case, I would do an override in the child, just so I could change the `@var` type.  I'll write that up in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve the need via a property override... this shouldn't hinder the code logic itself:

```
abstract class Controller {
   /** @var Service */
   public static $service;
   ...
}

abstract class UserController extends Controller {
   /** @var UserService */
   public static $service;

   public static function testService() {
      static::$service->testMethod();
   }
   ...
}
```

Side note: the `@var` syntax for class properties doesn't need the variable name repeated... that's only needed when `@var` is used to denote type on a local variable.  In the class property case, including the property name is actually just using the property name as the first word of the "description" portion.